# Get all timelines in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I get all timelines present in the scene of Unity and add them to my list?

```
private List<PlayableDirector> timelines = new List<PlayableDirector>();
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html ..?

Answer (score 0):

```
timelines = FindObjectsOfType<PlayableDirector>().ToList();
```